# How to simulate zener and normal silicon diodes in series to obtain IV curve (with icaps or any other simulation packages)?

Tags: diodes

I am trying to obtain the resultant IV curve of the combination of several zener diodes and a normal silicon diode in series.

As the zener diode would be working in reversed biased (and it is installed reversed). How do you incorporate that into [ICAPS](http://www.intusoft.com/icap.htm)?

Has anyone attempted to do this via simulation? An ICAPS example would help a lot!

Comment: I know nothing of icaps, but perhaps a voltage source would simulate a zener well enough IF there is net current flow into what would be the zener cathode.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about [ICAPS](http://www.intusoft.com/icap.htm) exactly, but since it's based on SPICE I think we can safely assume it does a DC Sweep.
For the Zener you would typically just use a zener model. If you have a particular part in mind check on the manufacturers website for SPICE models (example [here](http://www.diodes.com/products/spicemodels/category.php?category-id=4)) or look in the datasheet (often there is a .model listing)
This is how I would do it in LTSpice (I just picked the 4.7V Zener and standard diodes at random from the LTSpice library):

[image: ZenerIV]

[image: ZenerIV2]

Here is the Netlist:

> V1 V+ 0 15 Rser=0
>   D1 0 N002 1N750
>   D2 N001 N002 1N4148
>   D3 V+ N001 1N4148
>   .model D D
>   .lib C:\Program Files\LTC\LTspiceIV\lib\cmp\standard.dio
>   .dc V1 1m 10000m 1m
>   .backanno
>   .end

Comment: Very big thank you Oli! This simulation software seems a fair bit simplier. I'll give it a go.